# How do I apply a custom filter to some paths but not others in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security

I'm building a RESTful server, and I need to apply a custom filter to some paths but not others, but I'm doing something wrong. Here's my Security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final CustomFilter customFilter;

  @Autowired
  public AppSecurityConfig(CustomFilter filter) { customFilter = filter; }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .antMatcher("/auth/user/**")
      .addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

According to what I've read, the filter will be applied to any path starting with `/auth/user`, but not with, say, `/auth/admin`. But my filter logging is telling me that the filter gets applied to any request I make.

I don't have to worry about authentication because my server will only be visible to a single back-end application, which needs a secret key to connect. But I need this filter to work properly.

**Addendum:** I've added the annotations on the class for clarity. I should also mention that the filter extends OncePerRequestFilter:

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected  void doFilterInternal(
    final HttpServletRequest request,
    final HttpServletResponse response,
    final FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.trace("Executing CustomFilter");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is being applied to every request because it is probably a bean (annotated with `@Component`).

When you register a `Filter` as a bean, Spring Boot picks it up automatically and put it into the filter chain, note that this is not the Spring Security's `SecurityFilterChain`.

To avoid that, do not register your custom filter as a bean, just make it a regular Java object and register via `.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`, this way the `Filter` will only be present inside the `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added the annotations to the class for clarity. (Apologies for leaving them out. For security reasons, I can't copy and paste.) As you can see, my filter is not registered as a bean, although it is annotated as a Component. I removed the Component annotation and instantiated it internally in my AppSecurityConfig constructor, and now it works as I want it to. Thank you for pointing this out. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I also have to wonder if OncePerRequestFilter is the best filter to extend in this situation, or was it intended for the standard filter chain. Is there a better filter to extend?

Comment: It depends on your needs, if you don’t need OncePerRequestFilter you can implement Filter